# simple_token_authentication - undefined method `authenticate_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jwt

I am using [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and [simple_token_authentication](https://github.com/gonzalo-bulnes/simple_token_authentication) to create an API that supports token authentication

I have followed all the steps in the guide:

```
# app/models/user.rb

class User < ApplicationRecord

    acts_as_token_authenticatable

    # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

end
```

```
# app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User
end
```

When I try to reach a route "/books" to list all the entries of my model Book, I get the following error:

```
<NoMethodError:
    undefined method `authenticate_user!' for 
    # <BooksController:0x0000563e7bb26820>
    Did you mean?  authenticate_user_from_token!
>
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

More info:

```
$ rails routes
  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                            Controller#Action
   books GET    /books(.:format)                                       books#index
         POST   /books(.:format)                                       books#create
    book GET    /books/:id(.:format)                                   books#show
         PATCH  /books/:id(.:format)                                   books#update
         PUT    /books/:id(.:format)                                   books#update
         DELETE /books/:id(.:format)                                   books#destroy
sessions POST   /sessions(.:format)                                    sessions#create
         GET    /books/nearby/:latitude/:longitude/:distance(.:format) books#nearby
```

**UPDATE2**

I have made the whole repo public, if it helps. Look at the branch **simple_token_auth**
https://bitbucket.org/enmotent/bookaneer-api/src/master/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
    acts_as_token_authentication_handler_for User, fallback: :none
end

class BooksController < ApplicationController
 before_action :requires_login
end


 private
 def requires_login
   unless current_user
     render json: { errors: "This requires login" }
   end
 end
end
```

Comment: The book controller is the classic template that comes from scaffold a resource. There is absolutely nothing there. https://pastebin.com/MKqyz3QM

Comment: I don't see any issue on your controller could you show your routes please

Comment: sorry I don't see any issue on this also i cant tell what the problem actually is without seeing your all code. could you host your code to GitHub and provide link so that i can confirm where the issue actually is

Comment: The branch is called "simple_token_auth"

Comment: That way, I can get all my books, yeah... But even I did not provide any authentication data! That is also not the correct output.

Comment: Now I get an "NameError: undefined local variable or method `current_user"

Comment: just comment the `resources :sessions, only: [:create]` and uncomment `devise_for :users` on `routes.rb`

Comment: Works, but I cant set my own controller to authenticate...?